# Why isn't HtmlAttributeEncode method working in AntiXSS?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to implement the `HtmlAttributeEncode` method from the AntiXssEncoder class in the new System.Web.Security.AntiXss namespace.

The HtmlAttributeEncode method is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlattributeencode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Security_AntiXss_AntiXssEncoder_HtmlAttributeEncode_System_String_System_IO_TextWriter).

I am working in ASP.NET Web Forms. In the code below, S is a string and W is a TextWriter. To encode the string with VisualBasic.NET, I do this:

```
Dim W As System.IO.TextWriter = New StreamWriter("/text.txt")
Dim S As String = "Test"
S = AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(S, W)
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error message:

> AntiXssEncoder Protected Friend Overrrides Sub HtmlAttributeEncode (value as string, output as TextWriter) is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected Friend'.

The AntiXssEncoder class does not seem to recognize the `HtmlAttributeEncode` method. When I write this part of the code:

```
S = AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.
```

Intellisense suggests various methods that are available in the AntiXssEncoder class. For example, it suggests HtmlEncode and CssEncode as options. But it does not show HtmlAttributeEncode as a valid method in the AntiXssEncoder class.

How can I access the `HtmlAttributeEncode` method from the AntiXssEncoder class in the new System.Web.Security.AntiXss namespace?

Comment: It probably wants you to use `HtmlEncode` instead. Looks like `AntiXssEncoder` even encodes the same set of characters in both methods, so there’s no reason not to.

Comment: Hi, Ry. You’re right The two methods are very, very similar. But they’re not identical. The safe list for each method is slightly different. For example, HtmlEncode includes a space on the safe list; HtmlAttributeEncode does not.
In the documentation for HtmlAttributeEncode, Microsoft says the method is designed specifically for use in an HTML attribute. So, I thought that was the best one to use for HTML attributes, if I could get it to work.
I’m just wondering why it is not working for me. By the way, I'm following your advice and using HtmlEncode since that method works for me. Thanks.